# How do I return a string that includes new lines?

Tags: python

I have a question that requires I use `return` and I do not know how to return on multiple lines. I need to be able to get an output that looks like this

```
Dear so and so,
kjhagjkahgsdhgl;dslhglk
jkasdhgjkdshkglhds;g
kjdghksadjglkdjslkg
kjgahkjsdhlgkdsjg;lsd
```

where the gibberish are strings that I have

Answer (score 4):

You can use the newline escape sequence (`\n`):

```
return 'line1\nline2\nline3'
```

Or a multi-line string:

```
return '''line1
line2
line3'''
```

Or join a list of lines together:

```
return '\n'.join(['line1', 'line2', 'line3'])
```

Comment: when i use the first option it gives me an unexpected character after line continuation character error

Comment: when i use these they do not format correctly. The output is spaced where it should start a new line of text

Comment: @RyanBland: How are you using that function? That code works.

Comment: It is supposed to show on separate lines. When I run it is just adds the \n and not any actual line. It should read like a letter to someone

Comment: I need it to actually create a new line where the \n is and for me it isnt. I dont know if that because of my version (3.2) or not

Comment: @blandman1990: Right, but how are you using it? Do you `print` the results out? Can you just post *all* of your code?

Comment: It is for homework and the professor specifically asked for it to be returned. Printing is easy.

Comment: I had it working with print earlier but then I reread the question

Comment: @blandman1990: `\n` is how newlines are represented. If you literally had the characters `\n` in the resulting string, they would look like `\\n`. Everything's working as it should.

Comment: nope need it to look like an actually letter according to my professor

Comment: @blandman1990: No, that *is* exactly what it should look like. Email your professor if you don't believe me. Notice the quotes around the output. That's the *representation* of your resulting string. The newlines escape sequences are there so that you can read it as one line (and because the representation should generally be valid Python code).

Comment: is there any way to use return to get it to look like it should and not with representations of new line but actually new lines

Comment: @blandman1990: `print` it out. You cannot have literal line breaks like that. That's what the escape sequence is representing.

Comment: the question has a picture of what it is supposed to look like and this is not it.

Comment: ok, that is what I thought but he asked for it to be returned and to look a certain way, which he shows in the quesiton

Comment: @blandman1990: You're missing my point here. That *is* what it looks like if you `print()` it out, which is what the string *actually* looks like. What you see in the console is the representation of the object (`repr()`), which is just how the console displays it in order to let you see the newlines and special characters clearly.

Comment: I know exactly what you are saying. What Im saying is that he asked for it a certain way and showed what it is supposed to look like when the program is run through python with a screen shot of sample runs

Comment: Think of an acutally old letter with a dear line then on an entirely new line some words. a new line and words, etc. no representations of new lines but actual new lines.

Comment: @blandman1990: You're reading the professor's instructions a bit too literally.  Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about: http://i.imgur.com/l2kHRVK.png

Comment: ok, when i do this is has the /n in and doesn't read them correctly or start a new line like yours did.

Comment: @blandman1990: `\n` or `/n`? You cannot display a line break without `print`ing it out.

Comment: oh u used print, so there is no way to do it like he asks then?

Comment: So he apologized to the class for giving a problem that couldnt be done they way he asked

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with your code. It is working correctly. The only issue is confusion about the return value.

When you run a statement in the interactive Python interpreter, Python will print out the "representation" of the return value (unless it is `None`). The representation isn't the same thing as the value itself. You can get the representation of any object using the built-in `repr` function.

The `repr` of a string will include quotation marks, and will have all of the string's special characters escaped. The quotation marks and escape characters aren't actually part of the string itself, just part of the representation.

If you print out the string with `print(string)`, you'll see just the contents of the string, not anything that's only in the representation. There is no way to make a representation look like the printed output. Python just doesn't work that way. Probably the function you have is exactly what you need for your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
str1 + '\n' + str2.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = """hello world
goodbye mars"""

print(str)
```

Comment: `str` is abuiltin name, don't use it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
>>> print customSpam("John","Bob","Zoo")
```

If you just do this:

```
>>> customSpam("John","Bob","Zoo")
```

You will get the internal representation of the string, not how it would print once evaluated.